# Apigility 1.5.1 no RPC service routing in production mode

Tags: laminas-api-tools

As soon as I disable development mode, none of the RPC services are available any more.
Only the DefaultFrontend service with a Route to match of / returns the initial application page.
Any call to a Route to match other than / returns the usual 404 page with "Page not found. The requested URL could not be matched by routing. No Exception available"

When I enable development mode, my application works without errors and routing functions properly.

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the files in /data/cache after disabling development mode.

There were only two: module-config-cache.application.config.cache.php and module-classmap-cache.application.module.cache.php.

Apigility re-created them with updated versions and now routing functions properly in production mode.

Should Apigility not delete those files automatically when disabling / enabling development mode?